# Getting Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on a non-objectapp/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Config.php

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have this error message:

Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/live.mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Config.php on line 112

How to fix this?

This is only happen when importing data to database.This is working fine in my development server.

Comment: Have you tried googeling your question first? because i get plenty of answers when i do

Comment: i got several answers but those are not work for me.I got this error when changing my site to new server

Comment: In that case, I guess, you should mention all such relevant details in the question itself.